# update a date in txt file via php code ? or something else

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site and a code that when a user presses a button, a ONE off code is made and this code is outputted to two files

1 txt file, so it can be read against in case the user trys to cheat and wants to make a new code and the other in a format that will end the code on set date and time that my server reads.

The coder told me he can update this endate and would make the txt file 100% maintenance free for me and to date (3 months) has not done it and run off with money and is banned from freelancer.

Now i use the membership software AMEMBER as my main site and a custom code inside the site.php and a code called codegen.

Questions to people in the know, is how can i get this line of txt to update after a new payment from amember? mysql to txt?
cron every 1 min to check payments and lines?

any help please and im willing to pay if can be done right

the line in my test file is like this, example

> F: s11zPAj3z8 3nearsDvJQ { enddate=2017-07-11 2030 } # User ID: 54,
>   Name: Andrew Doyle #

So lets say the user pays for another month, the 07 would change to 08 or say a year , the year would go up by 1

Thanks for any help

Comment: why not use a database? So much simpler, safer if done properly and more reliable

Comment: love to use a db that can pull the info from amember on payment, but my server can ONLY read a txt file, php file in above format